# Como Obtener Mas De Un Resultado Con WebScrapping Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scrapping

Pues estoy intentando conseguir todos los resultados con el web scrapping, pero, al parecer solo me obtiene el primer dato, es decir, estoy intentando conseguir una lista de todas las casas y solo me encuentra la primera, alguien sabe el porque? Aqui va el codigo

```
# LIBRERIAS PARA EL WEB SCRAPPING

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# PAGINA WEB DE WEB SCRAPPING

url = requests.get('https://www.fotocasa.es/es/alquiler/todas-las-casas/girona-provincia/todas-las-zonas/l').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

# PARAMETROS PARA MI SCRAPPING

casas = soup.find_all('section', class_ = 're-SearchResult')
# BUCLE PARA CONSEGUIR TODAS LAS CASAS
for casa in casas:
    precio = casa.find('span', class_ = 're-CardPrice').text.replace(' ', '') # BUSCA LOS PRECIOS
    tipo_de_casa = casa.find('span', class_ = 're-CardTitle').text.replace(' ', '') # BUSCA EL TIPO DE CASA
    habitaciones = casa.find('span', class_ = 're-CardFeaturesWithIcons-feature-icon').text.replace(' ', '') # BUSCA LOS DETALLES
    metros = casa.find('span', class_ = 're-CardFeaturesWithIcons-feature-icon re-CardFeaturesWithIcons-feature-icon--surface').text.replace(' ', '')
    telefono = casa.find('a', class_ = 'sui-AtomButton sui-AtomButton--primary sui-AtomButton--outline sui-AtomButton--center sui-AtomButton--link re-CardContact-phone').text.replace(' ', '') '''

    print(f'''
    Tipo de casa : {tipo_de_casa}
    Habitaciones : {habitaciones}
    Metros : {metros}
    Precio : {precio}
    Contacto : {telefono}
    ''')

    print(' ')
```

Y cuando le doy print me printea lo siguiente :

```
Tipo de casa : CasaochaletenLloretdeMar
    Habitaciones : 3habs.
    Metros : 105m²
    Precio : 1.200€/mes
    Contacto : 972935680
```

Comment: Si le haces un print a casas cuantas te trae?

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich  mas de 10

Comment: Haz un print de casa luego del for y verifica si 5odas cumplen con los nombres de clases luego de la línea de teléfono hay tres ' es correcto? Luego del replace